# Why does my calculator in c++ subtract every two numbers I input, instead of doing the operations I asked it to do?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, calculator

[A simple calculator in C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QePw.png)

So, I've written this program, but when I put in any two numbers and a number that represents a operation, it always subtracts the two numbers, and I don't have any idea what's wrong...

Comment: please add the code.

Comment: Please paste your code into your question, and use the code field to format it. It's much easier to work with that way.

Comment: You should compare your code to [these calculator questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+calculator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (c = 1)
```

The `=` sign in C++ means *assignment*, not *comparison*. You need `==` (and in other three cases too).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have

```
if (c = 1) {
    ...
}
```

The expression `c = 1` assigns 1 to `c` and then returns 1, which is true, and thus it does the subtraction.

You meant to say

```
if (c == 1) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you've made the rookie mistake of C and C++'s comparison versus assignment operators.

```
if( c = 2 ) {
```

assigns the value of 2 to the variable `c` first and then tests for `true` or `false` (non-zero or zero in C/C++). In this case `2`, i.e. true.

You should've used:

```
if( c==2 ) {
```

because that compares the value of `c` with `2` and returns non-zero in case they're equal.

Comment: A good way to start the habit of making variables `const` by default, and paying attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: Certainly one of the best things to do!